# How to make div fill remaining vertical space using Flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to have 3  elements (a header, a footer, and some content) stacked vertically in the page. The header and footer div have a fixed height. How can I make the content div (the one in the middle) take up the remaining vertical space?

**My attempt with Flexbox**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header" />
    <div class="content" />
    <div class="footer" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps `flex-grow` or `height` might help?

Comment: `flex-grow` sounds like it's what you're looking for, but then the size of `.content` won't be affected by how much stuff it contains, which could cause problems - unless it's guaranteed to be less than `100vh - 60px` tall

Comment: @SoftwareStudent123 your divs does not have closing </div> fix that first

Answer (score 2):

Your css is already doing what you want to achieve.

`flex: 1` is shorthand for `flex-grow: 1`

As other items have fixed height, `flex: 1` causes your content to fill remaining space in your flexbox. The issue is however that your flexbox container doesn't have a height, if you want to cover the whole page you should add `height: 100vh` to your container.

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Also div is not a self closing element you need to close them as @Nutan Panta mentioned.

Comment: I would just add calc(100vh - {the body padding - 16px})

Comment: I never thought it could be done like this I usually don't do anything because after a certain space is taken by the content part the footer automatically comes to the bottom.

Comment: @MosheSommers well if we consider the body, best case would be resetting the default body margin and setting the height of the body as 100vh, then giving the wrapper div height: 100%.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu With you on that

Answer (score -2):

The footer does not need to at the bottom at the beginning after a certain space is taken by the content it will automatically will come at the bottom.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  height:200px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```